# Doubt in Package Indexing

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In indexing ROS packages there are three tags : doc,source and release. Can someone explain the use of each one ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317631/doubt-in-package-indexing/) by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you see whether [REP 141: ROS distribution files - Specification - Distribution file](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0141.html#distribution-file) clears this up?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0